# $L^{2}$ integrability implies $L^{1}$ integrability on sets of finite measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a measurable space with $m(X) < +\infty$. I think it's clear that if $f \in L^{2}(X)$ implies that $f \in L^{1}(X)$.

But when $m(X) = +\infty$, the suppose $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+|x|}$ is supposed to serve as an example of an $L^{2}$ function but not $L^{1}$. How would I go about seeing this?

I have seen a demonstration of this, but I didn't really get it. It was based on a proof of the first result, which I didn't follow. It went like this:

Let $A = \{x: |f(x)| \leq 1\}$ and $B = \{x : |f(x)| > 1\}$. Then we can write $$|f| \leq \chi_{A} + \chi_{B} \cdot |f|^{2}$$

Which somehow proves the first result. I can prove the first part on my own, but I just don't get why you bound $|f|$ in that particular way. What justifies it?

EDIT: The main part that I don't see is how $f \in L^{2}$, which is shown by writing $|f|^{2} \leq \chi_{[-1,1]} + \chi_{[1, \infty)} \cdot \frac{1}{x^{2}}$, but as in the first case, I don't see where this comes from.

Comment: I've added a new answer, this time hopefully answering the question you actually asked ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to pick a function which doesn't decay fast enough to be in $L^1$, but which *does* decay fast enough if squared. That works, of course, because squaring reduces the absolute value for numbers less than $1$. The simplest examples is $$
  f(x) = \begin{cases}
    \frac{1}{x} &\text{if $x > 1$} \\
    0 &\text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
$$
Since $$
  \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f|\,d\mu = \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x}\,dx = \ln x \big|_{x=1}^{x=\infty} = \infty \text{ you have } f \notin L^1 \text{,}
$$
but due to  $$
  \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f|^2\,d\mu = \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}\,dx = \frac{-1}{x} \big|_{x=1}^{x=\infty} = 1 \text{ you do have } f \in L^2 \text{.}
$$

The example in your works exactly the same. The only difference is that my example simply sets the function to zero left of $1$ to avoid the parts where $\frac{1}{x}$ would grow unbounded, whereas theirs replaces the denominator $x$ with $1+|x|$, which has a similar effect.